# Error: Undefined function or method 'estimateGeometricTransform'

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

I'm getting the following error when I try to run function m-file?

```
"Undefined function or method 'estimateGeometricTransform' for input arguments of type 'SURFpoints'.
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: if you're using a built in function,then perhaps that function is not available in your version of MATLAB. which version is yours?

Comment: And you could obviously check it by typing help estimateGeometricTransform in MATLAB's command window...

Comment: this function is a part of MATLAB 2013...according to my search

Comment: I use version R2012b.

What version should I use?

Comment: I think 2012 is good enough,even if your required function is not already available,I hope that you could create it with a lot less effort as compared to the previous version of MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have MATLAB release R2013a or later, and you need to have the Computer Vision System Toolbox.  If you have an older version of the Computer Vision System Toolbox, then you can use the `vision.GeometricTransformEstimator` system object instead of the `estimateGeometricTransform()` function.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform.html) documentation page, the function is part of the Computer Vision System Toolbox. It looks like that toolbox is not installed on your system. You can check what toolboxes are installed by typing `VER` into the command prompt.

Comment: may that toolbox is not installed on my system, what should I do?

Comment: Not necessarily. The toolbox might be installed and the error may have been triggered due to an invalid call. SURFpoints might not be of the type that estimateGeometricTransform expects.

Comment: You typically have to buy toolboxes separately - they can be quite expensive. See the math works [website](http://www.mathworks.com). Sometimes, if you just need one function for a specific case, you can write your own version with little effort.